Children's parent go missing; They realise that all the passers-by are following a fixed track
I saw this movie between year 2008-2009 when I was in high school. The movie can be classified as horror movie. The plot I can remember is that one family (parents and two children) went to a mysterious small town. On the road there is an old man that tells the children "don't believe anyone". While they went to the town, these children's parents were missing and two children entered a hotel. In the hotel, two children were asked to watch the pedestrian outside in the street. They find that all the people outside are following a fixed path. This is all I can remember.
Today, I mentioned this movie to my friends. However I cannot remember the name. Please help.
P.S. There maybe a town word in the name. But I am not sure. It is an English-speaking movie, most-likely American.

A lot of it sounds like Phantom Town from 1998.

When a sixteen year-old boy and his two young siblings set off on a quest to find their missing parents, their search leads them to a ghost town in the middle of the desert. They soon discover that this is no ordinary tourist spot. In fact, according to the maps, it doesn't exist at all! Finding their way into this mysterious place, the kids must confront the sinister force that dwells beneath it in order to rescue their parents - and save themselves.

I'm pretty sure that everyone in town behaved the same, and an old man in a gas station warns them not to trust anyone in that town on their way there. Here's the trailer:




It is the movie. Thank you very much.
